# Mysql Inner Join and Group By repeating row

Tags: mysql

I have problem with that more comments the comment table has. Then the more the `User` table repeating it value in the report group. It should only fetch user once, while comments as many there is which it is the current behaviour. But I would like the user being fetched once.

How it's now:

```
["text": "My first report",
user: [{"display_name": "Cyclops", "photo_url": "CYCLOPS_IMAGE.png",
{"display_name": "Cyclops", "photo_url": "CYCLOPS_IMAGE.png"},
{"display_name": "Cyclops", "photo_url": "CYCLOPS_IMAGE.png"}}],
comments: [{"text": "Great Report", display_name: "Xavier"},
{"text": "Bad Report", display_name: "Logan"},
{"text": "Thanks for the feedback", display_name: "Cyclops"}]]
```

What i expect:

```
["text": "My first report",
user: [{"display_name": "Cyclops", "photo_url": "CYCLOPS_IMAGE.png"}],
comments: [{"text": "Great Report", display_name: "Xavier"},
{"text": "Bad Report", display_name: "Logan"},
{"text": "Thanks for the feedback", display_name: "Cyclops"}]]
```

Code:

```
SELECT report.text, 
       Json_arrayagg(Json_object('display_name', users.display_name, 'photo_url', users.photo_url)) AS USER, 
       Json_arrayagg(Json_object('text', report_comments.text, 'display_name', report_comments.user_id)) AS COMMENTS 
FROM   report 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON users.id = report.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN report_comments 
              ON report_comments.report_id = report.id 
WHERE  report.user_id = :userId 
GROUP  BY report.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `report` to `users` is a `1:1` relationship, then you should be able to resolve your issue by doing the comment aggregation in a derived table, and joining to that instead:

```
SELECT report.text, 
       Json_arrayagg(Json_object('display_name', users.display_name, 'photo_url' 
                     , 
                     users.photo_url))                       AS USER,
       rc.COMMENTS
FROM   report 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = report.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT report_id,
         Json_arrayagg(Json_object('text', report_comments.text, 'display_name', 
                                   report_comments.user_id)) AS COMMENTS
  FROM report_comments 
  GROUP BY report_id
) rc ON rc.report_id = report.id 
WHERE  report.user_id = :userId 
GROUP  BY report.id
```

If a report can have multiple users, you will need to aggregate the user information in a derived table in the same manner.

Comment: This works great, the report has only one user. It's the `:userId`
If it's possible, comments has `display_name` but how can i return the `name` instead of the `user_id`

Comment: If there's a `display_name` column in `report_comments` you should be able to just replace `report_comments.user_id` in the arrayagg with `report_comments.display_name`? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: There is only `report_comments.user_id` i would like to retrive the `display_name` from `users` table by using the `report_comments.user_id`.

Comment: I see - give me a minute. btw are you running MySQL 5.7 or 8.0?

Comment: Thanks man i appericate it, 8.0. I just started with Mysql, so i'm learning

Comment: You'll need to join to the `users` table inside the subquery to get the user's displayname. See for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=646489be31923cad9ad8c231fc5fe1c4

Comment: Wow you're such a legend. Thank you very much! There is so many possibilities i did not know about how to achive things in Mysql.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8, take a look into [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) they're really useful constructs for making queries clearer to read. For this answer you could use one in place of the derived table

Comment: Thanks man, i'm trying to break down the code to understand and modify it a bit. By adding another table. `report_images` which has `report_id` and `image_path`. Which should include in the report. E.g  `images: [{"image_path": "cat.png"}, {"image_path": "dog.png"}],` Also trying add `COUNT(rc.comments) as totalC` but i retrive only 1 instead of number of comments

Comment: @Printer that's probably worth a new question. You can refer back to this one for context. But you will need to do the count inside the derived table.

Comment: I agree on that, i've made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546040/mysql-add-another-table-into-join