# Mysql Add another table into Join

Tags: mysql

i have a table i would like to add to my current Join:

Table (`report_images`) include a `report_id` and a `image_path`.

Reference: [Mysql Inner Join and Group By repeating row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545515/mysql-inner-join-and-group-by-repeating-row/65545588)

How it is now:

```
["text": "My first report", user: [{"display_name": "Cyclops", "photo_url": "CYCLOPS_IMAGE.png"}], comments: [{"text": "Great Report", display_name: "Xavier"}, {"text": "Bad Report", display_name: "Logan"}, {"text": "Thanks for the feedback", display_name: "Cyclops"}]]
```

What i expect:

```
["text": "My first report", user: [{"display_name": "Cyclops", "photo_url": "CYCLOPS_IMAGE.png"}], images: [{"image_path": "dog.png"}, {"image_path": "cat.png"}], totalComments: 3, comments: [{"text": "Great Report", display_name: "Xavier"}, {"text": "Bad Report", display_name: "Logan"}, {"text": "Thanks for the feedback", display_name: "Cyclops"}]]
```

Current code:

```
SELECT report.text, 
       Json_arrayagg(Json_object('display_name', users.display_name, 'photo_url' 
                     , 
                     users.photo_url))                       AS USER,
       rc.COMMENTS
FROM   report 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = report.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalComments, report_id,
         Json_arrayagg(Json_object('text', report_comments.text, 'display_name', 
                                   users.display_name)) AS COMMENTS
  FROM report_comments 
  JOIN users ON report_comments.user_id = users.id
  GROUP BY report_id
) rc ON rc.report_id = report.id 
WHERE  report.user_id = 4 
GROUP  BY report.id, rc.COMMENTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CTE-based solution which aggregates the user, image and comment information in CTEs and then joins all those CTEs to the `report` table to collect all the data together:

```sql
WITH user AS (
  SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('display_name', u.display_name, 'photo_url', u.photo_url)) AS user
  FROM users u
  WHERE id = 4
),
img AS (
  SELECT report_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('image_path', image_path)) AS images
  FROM report_images
  GROUP BY report_id
),
cmt AS (
  SELECT report_id, 
         JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('text', rc.text, 'display_name', u.display_name)) AS comments,
         COUNT(*) AS totalcomments
  FROM report_comments rc
  JOIN users u ON rc.user_id = u.id
  GROUP BY report_id
)
SELECT r.text,
       u.user,
       img.images,
       cmt.totalcomments,
       cmt.comments
FROM report r
JOIN user u ON u.id = r.user_id
LEFT JOIN img ON img.report_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN cmt ON cmt.report_id = r.id
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78c09d6ab10e52d2c912413a90caf2e0)

Comment: I'm so grateful for this, you're a saviour! I just got one question, is this faster than execute multiple queries which i before? Sinne it's Only one query.

Comment: There are actually 4 queries here, one for each CTE and one to give the final result by joining all the derived tables. Performance wise it wouldn't make much difference to write this as I have or as subqueries (as in your existing query), I just think this is a more readable way to write it.

Comment: Hi Nick, i noticed that nested array are returning as string and not json object. Any idea why?

Comment: @Printer JSON is a string format. If you want an object, you then need to decode the JSON; in PHP you would use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode); in JavaScript [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: I use `json_encode` in the PHP side. Then i use `json_decode` i'm able to access the first array. By doing E.g `data["user"]` but then inside that it's only a string not json array

Comment: I noticed the return is like this: `[{"photo_url": "https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png", "display_name": "Test User"}]` I dont think there should be `[]`

Comment: Assuming you read your table row into `$row`, you need to `json_decode($row['user'])`, `json_decode($row['images'])` and `json_decode($row['comments'])`. If you don't want an array around the `user` info, then remove the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` from that part of the query

Comment: As it now i use `json_encode($result)`. Before when i did it with a `foreach ($result as $key => $value) { $result[$key]["user"] = getUserById($db, $value["user_id"]); }` It works when i `decode` it later. Now it seems i need to `decode` twice.

Comment: Yeah, because your internal values in `$result` are already JSON encoded. I would decode them first as I suggested in my previous comment, and *then* `json_encode($result)`

Comment: When i try use `json_decode($result['user'])`` and also `print_r` to see if there is any effect. It shows nothing. While doing `json_decode($result[0])` shows the line. But when i `json_encode($result)` again after `decode` still the nested arrays are strings.

Comment: It seems we can't get enough information communicated through comments to figure out what's going on here. I suggest you ask another question. It would be helpful to show the code that you're using to run the query and fetch the results.

Comment: You're right, i created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603652/mysql-php-json-nested-array